# why is ApexChart x-axis title position bugging

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, apexcharts

[image]The x-axis title in my apexchart suddenly appeared overlapping on the graph as shown above (it should appear below the x-axis line), it was all fine before and I didn't change anything about its position.
My code to set x-axis is:

```
xaxis: {
   categories: [41, 42, 43],
   title: { text: "number of people" },
}
```

I'm using vue3-apexcharts 1.4.1 and apexcharts 3.36.3. This is bugging me for the past week and I couldn't fix it.
Is someone else also experiencing this problem or knows how to fix? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I noticed that. You have two solutions:

### Downgrade your version of ApexCharts

For instance, you can use this one: **3.35.1**

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    height: 350
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
    title: {
      text: 'Axis title'
    }
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.35.1"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

**Of course, if you do that, you will not have the latest enhancements:** [Releases · apexcharts/apexcharts.js · GitHub](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/releases)

### Use `xaxis.title.offsetY`

This is documented here: [xaxis – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/)

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    height: 350
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
    title: {
      text: 'Axis title',
      offsetY: 100
    }
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

**Be careful with this second solution because you may need some responsive rules...**

---

**EDIT**

After further investigation, it seems that this bug appeared with **v3.36.1**. Therefore, you can use **v3.36.0**.